# Format Exception Raises When Converting Simple Numeric String to Int in C#

Tags: c#, exception, numbers, format, type-conversion

I Had strange error when converting string in VS2015. When i use x variable, I got no error. Exception only raised when i used the date variable. Any Idea why???

Thanks

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = "9-1-2015";
            string date = "‎9‎-‎1-‎2015";
            List<string> dt = date.Split('-').ToList();
            List<int> lis = new List<int>();
            foreach (var item in dt)
            {
                lis.Add(int.Parse(item));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `date` variable value contains non-printable characters - U+200E in this case. (Copy and paste your string into http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer to see what I mean.) Without knowing where they come from, it's hard to know what to advise, but it's not a problem of converting a "simple numeric string".

Comment: Are you specially insert that symbol to improve rating?

Comment: I'm pasting it from kendoDatePicker Jquery Ajax POST value in MVC. Any idea how to convert these string to convertable format. Thanks.

Comment: If you've fixed the non-printable character issue you should use this instead: `DateTime dt; if(DateTime.TryParseExact("9-1-2015", "d-M-yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            { 
            
            }`. Then you have a `DateTime` variable which has properties like `Day`, `Month` or `Year`.

Comment: And I DON'T specially insert the symbol just for rating. I'm stuck with this problem for 2 days. I just want to convert the damn string to DateTime Object.

Comment: @JonSkeet: how can i remove those characters? I have tried `string.Concat(date.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)))` without success

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` is better than `int.Parse` since it returns 0 rather than an exception. But if you want exceptions then`TryParse` will be the best since it always handles exceptions by itself. And if you're working with dates then you could also use what @TimSchmelter suggested.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: `date = date.Replace("\u200e", "")` should work fine. (Your code doesn't work because it's a formatting character, not a control character.)

Comment: @Oceans: Why is returning 0 on failure better than an exception, in your view? (It only returns 0 on null input - `Convert.ToInt32("foo"))` will still throw.) And TryParse doesn't *handle* exceptions - it signals a failure to parse without using exceptions at all...

Comment: @JonSkeet: so is there no simple way to remove all invisible characters?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Well you could filter by whatever Unicode characters you want that includes Format as well as Control... but that can have a visible effect even if the character itself is not visible. In this case it would possibly be better to filter to only expected characters ('0'-'9' and '-').

Comment: What does the POST request body look like (check with F12 dev tools or Fiddler or something)? If the extraneous characters are already there in the request, the problem is on the kendoUI side (or at least, the client side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Tim Schmelter.

Yes indeed I need to clean my string var. Your code is very useful but it Doesn't work with my code. So I've modified the code to the below code.  Then I Can parse the cleanDate var to DateTime Object.

```
    string date = "9/28/2015 12:00:00 AM"; // In My Code, This Var Contain Unseen Unicode Char.
    var cleanDate = new string(date.Where(c => char.IsNumber(c) || char.IsPunctuation(c) || char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(cleanDate, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet [has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822367/format-exception-raises-when-converting-simple-numeric-string-to-int-in-c-sharp/32823036#comment53480207_32822367)

> Your date variable value contains non-printable characters, copy and paste your string into http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer

So you have to change the way it is generated or, if that's not possible/desired, remove them before you parse them to `DateTime`(which is what you actually want).

You can use this approach:

```
var unicodeCategories = new[] { UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber, UnicodeCategory.DashPunctuation };
string cleanDate = string.Concat(date.Where(c => unicodeCategories.Contains(char.GetUnicodeCategory(c))));
```

Now you can use `DateTime.TryParseExact`:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(cleanDate, "d-M-yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    Console.WriteLine("Year:{0} Month:{1} Day:{2}", dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Could not be parsed to DateTime");
```

Output with your `date`: `Year:2015 Month:1 Day:9`

Comment: I think one should first determine where these characters come from. In one of the comments, OP states he's using kendo date picker; are these characters already present in the request body (so the solution should be found client side)? Or are they added somewhere  server side during the request processing pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, below line has some hidden spaces:

```
string date = "‎9‎-‎1-‎2015";
```

Try moving your cursor with keyboard arrows on this line and you will get my point.

Try deleting this line and Rewrite the code for this line manually (without copy paste) and it will work